# Write into a file names of folders containing in C:\Program Files

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I have this task:
1. In current directory create file subMape.dat
2. Write into it all names of folders, that stored in C:\Program Files folder
3. Display on the screen data, that was written in subMape.dat

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    HANDLE f;
    HANDLE c = CreateFileW(L"subMape.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //TCHAR lpBuffer[32];
    DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead = 32;
    //DWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead;

    DWORD lengthSum = 0;

    if (c) {
        cout << "CreateFile() succeeded!\n";
        if(f = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\Program Files\\*", &findFileData)){ 
            if(f != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

                while (FindNextFile(f, &findFileData)){
                    lengthSum += bytesWritten;
                    WriteFile(c, findFileData.cFileName, (DWORD)wcslen(findFileData.cFileName), &bytesWritten, NULL);       
                }
            }
            FindClose(f);
        }

        else {
            cout << "FindFirstFile() failed :(\n";
        }

    }

    else {
        cout << "CreateFile() failed :(\n";
    }
    cout << lengthSum << endl;
    //SetFilePointer(c, lengthSum, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    //ReadFile(c, lpBuffer, lengthSum, &lpNumberOfBytesRead, NULL);
    //wprintf(lpBuffer);

    CloseHandle(c);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using UNICODE, when it writes findFileData.cFileName - it writes string, where characters splitted with spaces. For example: folder name "New Folder" (strlen = 10) will be written into the file as "N e w  T o" (strlen = 10). What do?

Comment: If you're using Unicode then you should `#define UNICODE` before you include windows.h. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Unicode

Comment: I tried, but this is not the correct solution.

Comment: I didn't say it was. I mention it because you're only inviting potential bugs by leaving it out. It's a requirement for working with Unicode.

Comment: It is set by the default in Visual Studio.

Comment: `if(c)` should be `if(c!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)`.

Comment: `WriteFile` takes a length in bytes, not characters, so use `wcslen(...) * sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: In the end I just switched off the UNICODE and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Your text file viewer or editor just isn't smart enough to figure out that you've written a utf-16 encoded text file.  Most text editors need help, write [the BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) to the file:

```
    cout << "CreateFile() succeeded!\n";
    wchar_t bom = L'\xfeff';
    WriteFile(c, &bom, sizeof(bom), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: It didn't worked well. It removed spaces in some strings, but it also messed up the other strings, that they're now not in recognizable symbols.For example: 7-䅚挀爀漀Ad䅯搀漀戀. Must be: 7-ZipAdobe...

Comment: Don't combine both answers.  If you write the BOM then don't also use WideCharToMultiByte().  Just the BOM is sufficient for your original code.

Comment: wchar_t bom = u'\xfeff'; ?

Comment: No, I used `wchar_t bom[] = L"\xfeff";`, single quotes and character U before string gives this errors: _syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'; 'u' : undeclared identifier; too big for character_.

Comment: Try to look at your file in a hexeditor. You are probably aware of this but if you write it as an array, do not add & before the identifier. You can also try const char bom[2]={0xff,0xfe};

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) to convert the UNICODE string to ANSI (or UTF8).

Comment: `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_COMPOSITECHECK , &findFileData.cFileName, bytesWritten, &lpBuffer, 32, NULL, NULL);`
Tried this before WriteFile(). Gives this error: error C2664: 'WideCharToMultiByte' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'TCHAR (*__w64 )[32]' to 'LPSTR'.

Comment: You'll notice that the type of parameter 5 is `LPSTR`, not `LPTSTR`.  The `TCHAR` type is something that changes between WCHAR and CHAR depending on the build configuration.  The output of `WideCharToMultiByte()` is based on CHAR regardless of whether your build is targeting UNICODE or not. Try changing the declaration of `lpBuffer` to `CHAR lpBuffer[32]`. Note that the same applies to the input of `WideCharToMultiByte()` - it's always based on `WCHAR` regardless of the build type. Also, `lpBuffer` is a misleading name for an array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see "space" is that the program you are using to list the file treats it as one byte per character. When using Unicode in windows you will get two, and the second byte is a '\0'.

You need to choose how you want to encode the data in the file.

The easiest you can do is to use `UTF-16LE`, since this is the native encoding on Windows. Then you only need to prepend a byte order marker to the beginning of the file. This encoding has an advantage over `UTF-8` since it is easy to destinguish from `extended ASCII` encodings due to the observed zero-bytes. Its drawback is that you need the `BOM` and it occupies more disk space uncompressed.

`UTF-8` has the advantage of being more compact. It is also fully compatible with pure `ASCII` and favoured by the programming community.

If you have do not need to use `extended ASCII` in any context, you should encode your data in `UTF-8`. If you do, use `UTF-16LE`.

Those who argue that a text that passes an `UTF-8` validation is encoded in `UTF-8` is right if the whole text is available, but wrong if it is not:

Consider an alphabetical list of swedish names. If I only check the first part of the list and it is `Latin-1` (`ISO/IEC 8859-1`), it will also pass the `UTF-8` test.

Then in the end comes "Örjansson" which breaks down into mojibake In fact 'Ö' will be an invalid `UTF-8` bit sequence. On the other hand, since all letters used actually fits in one byte when using `UTF-16LE`, I can be fully confident that it is not `UTF-8`, and not `Latin-1` either.

Comment: Text that is Latin-1 will not always also pass UTF-8.  Text that is ASCII will always pass UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If I had the entire text, it would probably not pass UTF-8. But I have not. A "normal text", or a list in the reverse order, will not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that in windows the "native" uncidode format is UTF-16 which is used by the W-style functions ( CreateFileW ). With that in mind writing the file should give you a valid UTF-16 text, but editor may not recognize that, to make sure your program works use a text editor where you can specify the encoding by hand ( you know what it needs to be ) in case it doesn't recognize it, for this Notepad++ is a good choice.

As others already mentioned, writing the BOM is very helpful for text editors and ensures that your file will be read correctly.

You can use WideCharToMultiByte to convert the UTF-16 into UTF-8 for even more compatibility.

And why did you use CreateFileW directly and not the FindFirstFileW do you have UNICODE defined in your project? If you do the compiler would resolve CreateFile into CreateFileW for you.

Also, here

```
WriteFile(c, findFileData.cFileName, (DWORD)wcslen(findFileData.cFileName), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

wcslen gives the number of characters which is not the same as the data size for a non ANSI text, it should be something like

```
wcslen(findFileData.cFileName)*sizeof(wchar_t)
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with UTF-16 files, it is important to write a byte-order mark and to write the data with lengths in bytes not characters.  `wcslen` returns the string length in characters but a character is two bytes when using wide strings.  Here's a fixed version.  It explicitly calls the wide version of the Win32 APIs so will work whether UNICODE/_UNICODE are defined or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW findFileData; // Use the wide version explicitly
    DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

    HANDLE f;
    HANDLE c = CreateFileW(L"subMape.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    DWORD lengthSum = 0;

    if(c != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "CreateFile() succeeded!\n";

        // Write A byte-order mark...make sure length is bytes not characters.
        WriteFile(c, L"\uFEFF", sizeof(wchar_t), &bytesWritten, NULL);
        lengthSum += bytesWritten;

        f = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\Program Files\\*", &findFileData);
        if(f != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

            while(FindNextFileW(f, &findFileData)) {
                // Write filename...length in bytes
                WriteFile(c, findFileData.cFileName, (DWORD)wcslen(findFileData.cFileName) * sizeof(wchar_t), &bytesWritten, NULL);
                // Add the length *after* writing...
                lengthSum += bytesWritten;

                // Add a carriage return/line feed to make Notepad happy.
                WriteFile(c, L"\r\n", sizeof(wchar_t) * 2, &bytesWritten, NULL);
                lengthSum += bytesWritten;
            }
            FindClose(f); // This should be inside findFirstFile succeeded block.
        }
        else {
            cout << "FindFirstFile() failed :(\n";
        }

        // these should be inside CreateFile succeeded block.
        CloseHandle(c);
        cout << lengthSum << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "CreateFile() failed :(\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```